# CSS font-size not working for h1 only in one block

Tags: html, css

I've looked around for a solution for this but it must be something a tad odd isnce bith the CSS and html verify with the w3c checker.

CSS Snippet:

```
body{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color:#000000;
    text-align: left;
  height:100%;
}

h1{
  font-size: 250%;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
}
h2{
  font-size:150%;
}
h1{
  font-size:120%;
}
#MainHeader{
  background-color:#efefef;
  background: url("http://www.wou.edu/images/spotlight/wounews.png") no-repeat;
  padding:15px 0px 15px 0px;
}
#MainContent{
  background: url("http://stuff.bodestone.net/jr/construction.gif");
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
  clear:both;
  background-color:#ff00ff;
  overflow:auto;
  height: auto;
}
#MenuBar{
  background-color:#dfdfff;
  float:left;
    padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
    overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
#PageContent{
  float:left;
  background-color:#dedebe;
  overflow: auto;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
  <body>
    <div id="MainHeader">
      <h1>A random template site to work some stuff out</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="MainContent" class="clearfix">
      <div id="MenuBar">
        <a href="index.html" class="here">Page 1</a><br>
        <a href="page2.html">Page 2</a><br>
        <a href="page3.html">Page 3</a><br>
      </div>
      <div id="PageContent">
        <h2>This is page 1</h2>
        <p>lar</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Footer" class="clearfix">
      <span style="float:left">And here we have a footer.</span><span style="float:right">Style info for left and right defined separately in the html.</span>
    </div>
  </body>
```

If I change the font-weight of h1 it changes. If I change the font-size it does not.
I can change weight and size of the h2 in the PageContent DIV.

As an aside, I have used * before for global definitions at the start of the style sheet. Is this the same as root?

Comment: The * is not the root, it's a wildcard matching any element. Use body or html as the root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to define font size for `h1` twice:

```
h1{
  font-size: 250%;     /* Here */
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
}
h2{
  font-size:150%;
}
h1{
  font-size:120%;      /* And here */
}
```

Depending on which you're changing, you might not see results, because the second `h1` rule is overriding that of the first. If you're modifying the first declaration, then it will be overridden by the second declaration.

The validator does not warn about rules with identical selectors that may override one another, so you'll have to watch out for that yourself, or check with a tool like Firebug to see the computed style for an element.

> As an aside, I have used * before for global definitions at the start of the style sheet. Is this the same as root?

No, `*` is the universal selector that matches any element. The root element is `html`, but even by applying styles to that element, not every style will be inherited by `body` elements inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have h1 defined twice in your CSS - above and below h2.

Both of them seem to have font-size defined. Delete the second one.

Comment: OK so you spotted my daftness too but the other answer was first and quoted for completeness so got the answer.

Comment: @Bodestone: If you want to accept an answer based on who came first, well, I did.

Comment: @boltClock Sorry I have this open on the lappy with very little vertical screen res an ticked the wrong one. Yours was also the most complete in quoting the error too.

Comment: @Bodestone: Oh, it's fine. I wasn't complaining or anything :)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have defined h1 twice in your css.

```
h1{
  font-size: 500%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

h1{
  font-size:120%;
}
```

First value gets overridden by the second value. So the size doesn't change :)

Comment: I am a muppet!
Simple cut and paste error staring me in the face all along. I knew it would be something daft but reading and re-reading my brain autmatically made the last one a 3.

Comment: Aw, those are the worst. I didn't read your aside question at first, but like BoltClock said, the asterisk matches any element. It's basically a wildcard. Some people use it to reset their margins and padding at the start of a document, however I prefer to use Meyer's reset.css (would link if I knew how).

Comment: Yeah, `*` is performantly quite bad. It doesn't *visibly* slow down a browser, of course, but it's still enough to warrant not using it for reset styles at all.